# App engine Java - Dev server datastore not saved after restart

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

I work on an app in Android Studio with a backend module, every time i restart the development server the datastore gets deleted.

Is there a cmd option to save the datastore upon restart ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Mac OS X? By default (I think!) dev_appserver is in a temporary folder, which gets deleted every time the *machine* restarts.

I'm assuming you are using the java for your appengine backend.

You can use the `--generated_dir` [option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments) to set the datastore location to a non-temporary location that will persist between reboots.

e.g.

```
dev_appserver --generated_dir=$HOME/mydatastore .
```